# Is there a built-in function that checks if a variable is a cell of a minimum length in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is there a built-in function that checks if a variable is a cell array is of a minimum `numel` in Matlab?

In contrast, `validattributes` can be used to check if a variable is of an exact length with the `'numel',N` attribute. Is there a way to make `validattributes` check minimum length instead?

If you are interested, I am using it to enforce the number of input arguments for a function with `varargin`.

Comment: Why do you need a built-in function?

Comment: How else do you suggest doing it? A loop?

Comment: I thought one could pass a custom function handle to validateattributes, but that is obviously wrong.

Comment: @PatrickHappel: Well, I wonder why that isn't the case.

Comment: Maybe because you can pass a custom function handle to `inputParser`'s `add...` methods?!

Comment: @PatrickHappel: Those methods are restricted in other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [`narginchk`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/narginchk.html)? This will give you a sensible error if insufficient inputs are provided.

Comment: Because I am not directly checking the number of inputs in the functions, but instead using [`inputParser`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser.html) elsewhere that would call those functions, where unmatched inputs can be stored away without throwing errors. Right now, it's just for debugging purpose. I am not sure if it'd be useful if not for debugging. But that's why I was curious if there is a way to do it generally. Thank you for linking `narginchk` though!